# codeigniter not reliable when updating queries

Tags: codeigniter-3

Am currently using codeigniter for a project. The update query is not reliable. It works for a while and then begin to malfunction. Its very frustrating. Here is the code am using

```
function update_data($table,$where,$data) //updates data of a table 
{
    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->update($table);
}
```

Usage:

```
  $data['id]=1;
  $data['name'] = 'test';
  update_data(PRODUCTS,array('id'=>$id),$data);
```

Comment: To help it would be good to know what "malfunction" means. What is going wrong?

Comment: In the "Usage" code above you pass `array('id'=>$id)` to `update_data'. Where does the variable `$id` come from?